# RuntimeError: shape '[1, 1, 223232]' is invalid for input of size 446464

Tags: python, torch, librosa

I have this error (RuntimeError: shape '[1, 1, 223232]' is invalid for input of size 446464), when I was executing the colab
[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlrIC.png)

I was trying to use this github proyect (https://github.com/BenAAndrew/Voice-Cloning-App/releases/tag/v1.1.1) to make voice models on google colab, I changed a few things that made problems, like the version of librosa, I installed librosa 0.9.1 with pip, and I changed the ubication of the pretrained model because It does not launch with the default setting, This was the code before:
[Google colab of github version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwjYX.png), and I changed to this:
[Google colab that I changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGUWH.png) note that Jaia is a folder on my google drive and I uploaded the file there, below I attach a link to the real colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YbB_gA2_Rspmm1TDyEDueNXittmtWu1c?usp=sharing#scrollTo=JxSWGygYnz6R

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Okay, and what is your question?

Comment: How can I resolve it?

Comment: Use a shape that matches the given size, or use a size that matches the shape. Presumably when multiplying the elements of the shape, the result must be equal to the size.